# How to determine whether a website is FTP or HTTP?

Tags: http, ftp

The public website  [opendata.dwd.de](http://opendata.dwd.de/) can be accessed either by `http://` or `ftp://` in the web browser. 
When I use `curl -I http://opendata.dwd.de/`, the response header is:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Fri, 30 Nov 2018 06:59:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000`

The HTTP response header doesn't show any information about FTP.

I guess it is a FTP server so I use `curl ftp://opendata.dwd.de/` to access the server, the response is the directory structure:

`-rw-rw-r--    1 5521     15101         528 Jul 25  2017 README.txt
drwxrwxr-x    2 5521     15101        4096 Jul 06  2017 climate
drwxr-xr-x    4 5521     15101       12288 Nov 27 11:39 climate_environment
drwxrwxr-x    3 5521     15101        4096 Sep 20 12:15 test
drwxrwxr-x   13 5521     15101        4096 Nov 30 07:03 weather`

But the response header doen't contain anything.

Another public website http://dd.meteo.ec.gc.ca/ looks like an FTP server, but I can't use FTP to access it at all. **And I don't know whether it is an FTP server or not.**

Using Firefox Developer Tools Networks tab produces the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the response header doen't contain anything.

There is no such thing as a response header with FTP.

> How to determine whether a website is FTP or HTTP?

HTTP and FTP are completely different protocols used to access content provided by a server. FTP is usually used to access static resources (files) while HTTP is used for both static and dynamically created content - but in theory one could serve dynamic content with FTP too if one would implement an FTP server which generates content on demand.

If you can access the resource with `http://` or `https://` it is obviously HTTP. If you can access it with `ftp://` (or with some FTP client like `ftp`) it is obviously FTP. It might also be possible that you can access it with both and also that you can access it with sftp, rsync, SMB, ... or other protocols. And it is also possible that a server provides access for both HTTP and FTP but provides different resources there.

HTTP and FTP are essentially different doors into the same house (the server). Both doors might exists, none might exist or only one. Both doors might lead into the same room or into different rooms (provide same or different content). And both doors need to be opened in a different way (different application protocol).